# How to execute functions inside a running JS function - modifying a JS game

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify a js game which executes as a single function.

I have a user prompt from the main html (facebook sharing stuff) that is triggered inside the game and overlays it momentarily. As a result I want to execute a function inside the game (to effect game play). Any ideas?

I'm on my learning way with js and might be missing something....

Thanks for the quick suggestions!

The game is executed as a function in the html GameFunction(parameters...)
In the game on a game over condition the  game executes

```
$('#fbForm').show();
```

---

```
<div id="fbForm" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; z-index: 20; display: none">
<form  method="" action="" >
<fieldset>    
 <label >Share on FB</label>
<input type="button" name="close" class="button" id="close" value="Play!" onclick="postToFeed();"   />
<input type="button" name="close" class="button"  id="x" value="x" onclick="XXX"  />
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

When button #x is clicked is there a way to execute the game over function inside GameFunction()  ??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're question is pretty vague and open ended, and questions on SO often have a code snippet involved. You might want to make the question a little more specific, and give the community an impression of what you're tried (in code) or your question might be [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Comment: @zonda1 - please provide some specific code that shows what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestions!

The game is executed as a function in the html
In the games JS on a game over condition the  game executes

$('#fbForm').show();

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you've got code something like this:

```
function GameFunction (foo, blah) {
    // does lots of stuff here

    function GameOverStart () {
        // does some stuff
        $('#fbForm').show();
    }

    function GameOverFinish () {
        // does some more stuff, like hide the form
    }
}
GameFunction(1.0, 2.5);
```

And you want your button #x to call your nested GameOverFinish function.

Option 1: Save GameOverFinish as a global variable (ie as a property of 'window'):

```
    window.GameOverFinish = function () {
        // does some more stuff, like hide the form
    };
```

and your html should be

```
    <input type="button" name="close" class="button"  id="x" value="x" onclick="window.GameOverFinish()"  />
```

Option 2: Use jQuery to bind the button during the execution of GameFunction (see http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
    function GameOverFinish () {
        // does some more stuff, like hide the form
    }
    $('#x').click(GameOverFinish);
    // no HTML 'onclick' value is needed in this case
```

Comment: thank!! will try -- just used the magical getElementById  and created a global function to bind inside the game to assign onClicks - works so far so good

but wil try the other options too!